# Access list of tabs for a given profile using tooling api

Tags: community, tooling-api

When i try using tooling api with below code snippet i am getting empty list in tabVisibilities attribute. Any inputs will be of great help to the team.

### Code Snippets

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: GS.sessionId}); 
                  conn.tooling.sobject('Profile')
                    .find({Id:'00e90000001XS1G'})// hard coded the profile id
                    .execute(function(err, records) {
                        if (err) { return console.error(err); }
                        for (var i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
                          var record = records[i];}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I assume you are looking at the tabVisibilities via the [Profile.Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_profile.htm?search_text=Profile). Ref [ProfileTabVisibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#profiletabvisibility_title).

Are the tabVisibilities that you are trying to retrieve Hidden? If so, they aren't retrieved by the API currently (Spring '16).

See [Metadata API: Hidden tabVisibilities are not retrieved for Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Metadata-API-Hidden-tabVisibilities-are-not-retrieved-for-Profile&language=en_US).

You might like to vote for the idea [Metadata API: Hidden tabVisibilities are not retrieved for Profile](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnXrAAK)